# simple angular example not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've duplicated [an angular example from w3schools (here)](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_controllers.asp), and it's not working. I don't understand why. It looks like it should be working fine. What am I doing wrong?

[Here's a plunker of my experiment](http://plnkr.co/edit/7DBZn7yIIhpjiYplbT6m?p=preview)

Here's the angular JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('thingsCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.things = [
       {title: 'my title 1', content: 'my Content 1'},  
        title: 'my title 2', content: 'my Content 2'}, 
        title: 'my title 3', content: 'my Content 3'}, 
        title: 'my title 4', content: 'my Content 4'},  
        title: 'my title 5', content: 'my Content 5'},
        title: 'my title 6', content: 'my Content 6'}
        ];

    $scope.things2 = [
       {title: 'my 2nd title 1', content: 'my Content 1'},  
        title: 'my 2nd title 2', content: 'my Content 2'}, 
        title: 'my 2nd title 3', content: 'my Content 3'}, 
        title: 'my 2nd title 4', content: 'my Content 4'},  
        title: 'my 2nd title 5', content: 'my Content 5'},
        title: 'my 2nd title 6', content: 'my Content 6'}
        ];
});
```

Here's the HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

     <!-- CSS  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!-- JS  -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

  </head>

<body>  

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="thingsCtrl">
        <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>



      <div class="container">   
          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sx-6"><h4>My Subtitle</h4>
                <div ng-repeat="x in things"> 
                    <div class="col-sx-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
                  <div class="cube">
                    <b>{{x.title}}</b> </br> {{x.content}}

                  </div>                
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sx-6"><h4>My Subtitle</h4>
                <div ng-repeat="x in things2"> 
                    <div class="col-sx-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
                  <div class="cube">
                    <b>{{x.title}}</b> </br> {{x.content}}

                  </div>                
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>

          </div>
      </div> 

    </div>     

    <script src="script.js"></script>     

      </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not opening another key/value array for each item in your list.

```
    {title: 'my title 2', content: 'my Content 2'}, 
    title: 'my title 3', content: 'my Content 3'},
```

Try:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('thingsCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.things = [
       {title: 'my title 1', content: 'my Content 1'},  
        {title: 'my title 2', content: 'my Content 2'}, 
        {title: 'my title 3', content: 'my Content 3'}, 
        {title: 'my title 4', content: 'my Content 4'},  
        {title: 'my title 5', content: 'my Content 5'},
        {title: 'my title 6', content: 'my Content 6'}
        ];

    $scope.things2 = [
       {title: 'my 2nd title 1', content: 'my Content 1'},  
       {title: 'my 2nd title 2', content: 'my Content 2'}, 
       {title: 'my 2nd title 3', content: 'my Content 3'}, 
       {title: 'my 2nd title 4', content: 'my Content 4'},  
       {title: 'my 2nd title 5', content: 'my Content 5'},
       {title: 'my 2nd title 6', content: 'my Content 6'}
        ];
});
```

Oh, and check the console error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'myCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

Your myApp controller is incorrect.

Comment: Got it, I knew it had to be something stupid o.O! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You have specified wrong controller in markup. Update

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
```

to

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="thingsCtrl">
```

Comment: Thanks, doh, I changed that a moment ago and forgot to change the markup. Updated in plunkr and above, it's still not working tho'.

Comment: Thats because your json is incorrect - you were missing { in your json. Here is the updated plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/FOKhJfSvOxIZn2Rpvvo9?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I notice that your object array syntax is incorrect, missing a curly brace before each object.

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('thingsCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.things = [
   {title: 'my title 1', content: 'my Content 1'},  
    {title: 'my title 2', content: 'my Content 2'}, 
    {title: 'my title 3', content: 'my Content 3'}, 
    {title: 'my title 4', content: 'my Content 4'},  
    {title: 'my title 5', content: 'my Content 5'},
    {title: 'my title 6', content: 'my Content 6'}
    ];

  $scope.things2 = [
   {title: 'my 2nd title 1', content: 'my Content 1'},  
    {title: 'my 2nd title 2', content: 'my Content 2'}, 
    {title: 'my 2nd title 3', content: 'my Content 3'}, 
    {title: 'my 2nd title 4', content: 'my Content 4'},  
    {title: 'my 2nd title 5', content: 'my Content 5'},
    {title: 'my 2nd title 6', content: 'my Content 6'}
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell angular order of dependencies. You want the `$scope` injected to so you mention that to angular. for example, if I wanted to inject the `$q` as well, I would add that to the list as such `.controller('thingsCtrl', ['$scope', '$q', function($scope, $q) { ... }]);`  Code below should work fine

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('thingsCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.things = [
        {title: 'my title 1', content: 'my Content 1'},  
        {title: 'my title 2', content: 'my Content 2'}, 
        {title: 'my title 3', content: 'my Content 3'}, 
        {title: 'my title 4', content: 'my Content 4'},  
        {title: 'my title 5', content: 'my Content 5'},
        {title: 'my title 6', content: 'my Content 6'}
        ];

    $scope.things2 = [
        {title: 'my 2nd title 1', content: 'my Content 1'},  
        {title: 'my 2nd title 2', content: 'my Content 2'}, 
        {title: 'my 2nd title 3', content: 'my Content 3'}, 
        {title: 'my 2nd title 4', content: 'my Content 4'},  
        {title: 'my 2nd title 5', content: 'my Content 5'},
        {title: 'my 2nd title 6', content: 'my Content 6'}
        ];
}]);
```